# How to show a List item after click button in react native

Tags: react-native

I'm a new to react-native and i need a help. I want to do this: I have a button, when click it, a list item will show under the button. Help me guys !

Thanks

Comment: can you give some code please ? :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use or learn (if you want make your own popover) from [react-native-list-popover](https://github.com/bulenttastan/react-native-list-popover/blob/master/ListPopover.js). Here some screenshot from reace-native-list-popover:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make a Boolean flag in your component state and initiate it with `false` and then use it for showing the list. You can use `FlatList` for make a good list.

The example code can be like this:

```
export default class ClassName extends Component {
  state = {showList: false}

  _onPress = () => {
    this.setState({showList: true})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button onPress={this._onPress}>Show List</Button>
        {(this.state.showList) && <FlatList
          data={[{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'}]}
          renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>}
        />}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```